# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1048

Tags: php, mysql

Error Number: 1048

Column 'nama' cannot be null

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`nama`, `email`, `password`, `satker`, `insert_at`, `update_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '$2y$10$nXUVD6prTU3RHgicGFUokesJH3qMpeXtsTGF1.dIzBX2qfyiIj2kG', NULL, 1585030035, 1585030035)
```

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/boroom/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: The error message seems clear. Your table definition says `nama NOT NULL`, but you're trying to insert `NULL` in that column.

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE user;` ,copy the result then [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60825769/edit)

Comment: More importantly, show your PHP code, so we can see where the null values are coming from.